# sync local folder structure to s3 root structure

Tags: amazon-s3

In my pipeline I am trying to sync my local folder (or should I say repository folder) to the s3 bucket. Now I can do the `aws s3 sync . s3://` but this off course gives an error, since the bucket is not specified. But basically that is exactly what I want. Exactly how my folder-structure locally is; is how I want in S3.

so locally:

- bucket1/file1.txt
- bucket1/file2.txt
- bucket1/subbucket1/file3.txt

needs to go exactly to root of my s3 account... how to fix this?

btw; the `sync` might be an overkill since I only want to copy (and overwrite!) to the s3 folders, coming from the root. Not (yet) interested in deleting etc.

what can I do..?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if somebody comes to the same question:

```
for file in `find -type f`;
do
newFilename="${file#./}"
dirName=$ENVIRONMENT-$(dirname "$newFilename")

#get first part of dir (only root)
dirName="${dirName%%/*}"

echo bucket: $dirName

if aws s3api head-bucket --bucket "$dirName" 2>/dev/null; then
   echo "bucket already exists"
else
  if [[ $dirName == *"/"* ]]; then
     echo $dirName
     echo "This bucket is a subfolder and will not be created"
  else
     aws s3 mb s3://$dirName
  fi
fi

aws s3 cp $newFilename s3://$ENVIRONMENT-$newFilename
done
```

the scripts retrieves all the files that it can find;
then it will check the root directory (relative to the current folder)
it will check it the directory exists as a bucket. If not; it will be created.
And then every file will be copied.

Since i do not know if a root-directory exists (as a bucket) we have to manually check it. 
I couldn't use the `sync` because I might not have an existing bucket.
If you do know that your root directory as a bucket exists; then i would use the sync, one liner vs 10-liner :see_no_evil:.

anyway, that was it for me!

Answer (score 0):

The [AWS Command-Line Interface (CLI)](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/) `aws s3 sync` command *requires* a bucket name.

Therefore, you will either need to write a script that extracts the bucket name and inserts it into the `aws s3 sync` command, or you'll need to write your own program to use in place of the AWS CLI.

If you have a limited number of buckets and they don't change that often, you could just write a script that repeatedly calls the AWS CLI, such as:

```
aws s3 sync bucket1/ s3://bucket1/
aws s3 sync bucket2/ s3://bucket2/
etc.
```

Comment: it are manu buckets propably :see_no_evil:  but doing it with several steps, so i can extract the bucket-name; but if fails now if the bucket name does not exists yet. as a test `aws s3 sync . s3://bucketdoesnotexist-test --exclude "*" --include "*.txt"`

Comment: does that mean that for a sync operation the bucket always have to exists? i thought that there were no 'buckets'..

Comment: Yes, a bucket must exist to interact with it. There are buckets, but there are no "folders" (you can copy files to a path that doesn't exist and it will work just fine).